# Firefox or Falkon Sometimes Freezing -- 4 years old machine

Tags: lubuntu, firefox, freeze

I am trying to use my old computer for development purposes (LAMP), and I decided to run lubuntu expecting a good performance but no luxury. So installed it from a live image and installed libreoffice, mysql and php ... Basically just that.

Well, most of the time the computer response is acceptable, but the browser (independently whether it is Falkon or Firefox) freezes from time to time (while I am developing or not), particularly if they are running for more than 1 hour. No response for any click, even if I click on a different application (gedit, for instance). I have to patiently wait.
After noticing these issues I created a 8GB SWAP memory. The freezes still happen

Using ***htop*** I noticed when the issue happens that Firefox is apparently consuming most of the CPU, the RAM memory is "almost full" (but the Swap memory is just below 50%).

> comment: htop was assessed after the freeze happened, as meanwhile the screen was "frozen".

```
gustavo@gustavo-spinsp11133:~$ free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.6Gi       2.6Gi       290Mi       555Mi       790Mi       287Mi
Swap:          8.3Gi       3.1Gi       5.2Gi
```

My current workaround is to close the browser and reopen it after waiting patiently. Voila! The problem is fixed, as if nothing had happened.

I am afraid that today's browsers cannot run with 1.1GHZ 4GB RAM anymore :-( , but actually, I remember times when we run a browser with 64MB of ram...

Questions

- I **suspect** that the kernel config is not properly set to this machine, **where can I find a way to setup it correctly?**
- How to configure (*if possible*) Falkon or, preferably, Firefox to run in a low profile computer?

info from **hardinfo**

```
-Computer-
Processor       : Intel(R) Celeron(R) N4020 CPU @ 1.10GHz
Memory      : 3819MB (2629MB used)
Machine Type        : Laptop
Operating System        : Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
User Name       : gustavo (Gustavo Laufer)
Date/Time       : Tue 20 Jun 2023 08:45:28
-Display-
Resolution      : 3926x1440 pixels
OpenGL Renderer     : Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics 600 (GLK 2)
X11 Vendor      : The X.Org Foundation
-Audio Devices-
Audio Adapter       : HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
-Input Devices-
 Lid Switch
 Power Button
 Power Button
 AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
 Video Bus
 Acer Wireless Radio Control
 06CB0001:00 06CB:CD3F Mouse
 06CB0001:00 06CB:CD3F Touchpad
 Acer WMI hotkeys
 FTSC1000:00 2808:509C
 FTSC1000:00 2808:509C UNKNOWN
 VGA WebCam: VGA WebCam
 HDA Intel PCH Mic
 HDA Intel PCH Headphone
 HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm:3
 HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm:7
 HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm:8
 HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm:9
 HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm:10
 Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0
 Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0 Mouse
 Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0 Consumer Control
 Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0 Consumer Control
 Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0 System Control
-Printers-
No printers found
```

**Operating System**

```
Kernel      : Linux 5.19.0-43-generic (x86_64)
Version     : #44~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon May 22 13:39:36 UTC 2
C Library       : GNU C Library / (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.35-0ubuntu3.1) 2.35
Distribution        : Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
-Current Session-
Computer Name       : gustavo-spinsp11133
User Name       : gustavo (Gustavo Laufer)
Language        : LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=en_AU.UTF-8;LC_TIME=en_AU.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=en_AU.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=en_AU.UTF-8;LC_NAME=en_AU.UTF-8;LC_ADDRESS=en_AU.UTF-8;LC_TELEPHONE=en_AU.UTF-8;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_AU.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_AU.UTF-8 (en_GB.UTF-8)
Home Directory      : /home/gustavo
-Misc-
Uptime      : 4 days 16 hours 5 minutes
Load Average        : 1.32, 1.36, 1.74
Available entropy in /dev/random        : 256 bits (medium)
```

**Kernel modules**

```
    -Loaded Modules-
    cpuid       : x86 generic CPUID driver
    nfnetlink       : Netfilter messages via netlink socket
    ccm     : Counter with CBC MAC
    rfcomm      : Bluetooth RFCOMM ver 1.11
    cmac        : CMAC keyed hash algorithm
    algif_hash
    algif_skcipher
    af_alg
    bnep        : Bluetooth BNEP ver 1.3
    snd_sof_pci_intel_apl
    snd_sof_intel_hda_common
    soundwire_intel     : Intel Soundwire Link Driver
    soundwire_generic_allocation        : SoundWire Generic Bandwidth Allocation
    soundwire_cadence       : Cadence Soundwire Library
    snd_sof_intel_hda
    snd_sof_pci
    snd_sof_xtensa_dsp      : SOF Xtensa DSP support
    snd_sof     : Sound Open Firmware (SOF) Core
    snd_sof_utils
    soundwire_bus       : SoundWire bus
    snd_soc_avs     : Intel cAVS sound driver
    snd_soc_skl     : Intel Skylake ASoC HDA driver
    intel_pmc_bxt       : Intel Broxton PMC driver
    snd_soc_hdac_hda        : ASoC Extensions for legacy HDA Drivers
    intel_telemetry_pltdrv      : Intel SoC Telemetry Platform Driver
    snd_hda_ext_core        : HDA extended core
    snd_soc_sst_ipc     : Intel SST IPC generic
    intel_rapl_msr      : Driver for Intel RAPL (Running Average Power Limit) control via MSR interface
    intel_punit_ipc     : Intel P-Unit IPC driver
    intel_telemetry_core        : Intel SoC Telemetry Interface
    snd_soc_sst_dsp     : Intel SST Core
    x86_pkg_temp_thermal        : X86 PKG TEMP Thermal Driver
    snd_soc_acpi_intel_match        : Intel Common ACPI Match module
    snd_soc_acpi        : ALSA SoC ACPI module
    snd_soc_core        : ALSA SoC Core
    intel_powerclamp        : Package Level C-state Idle Injection for Intel CPUs
    coretemp        : Intel Core temperature monitor
    snd_compress        : ALSA Compressed offload framework
    ac97_bus
    snd_hda_codec_hdmi      : HDMI HD-audio codec
    snd_pcm_dmaengine
    kvm_intel
    snd_hda_codec_realtek       : Realtek HD-audio codec
    snd_hda_codec_generic       : Generic HD-audio codec parser
    ledtrig_audio       : LED trigger for audio mute control
    snd_hda_intel       : Intel HDA driver
    snd_intel_dspcfg        : Intel DSP config driver
    kvm
    snd_intel_sdw_acpi      : Intel Soundwire ACPI helpers
    uvcvideo        : USB Video Class driver
    snd_hda_codec       : HDA codec core
    rapl
    snd_hda_core        : HD-audio bus
    btusb       : Generic Bluetooth USB driver ver 0.8
    videobuf2_vmalloc       : vmalloc memory handling routines for videobuf2
    intel_cstate
    snd_hwdep       : Hardware dependent layer
    videobuf2_memops        : common memory handling routines for videobuf2
    serio_raw       : Raw serio driver
    btrtl       : Bluetooth support for Realtek devices ver 0.1
    binfmt_misc
    btbcm       : Bluetooth support for Broadcom devices ver 0.1
    btintel     : Bluetooth support for Intel devices ver 0.1
    btmtk       : Bluetooth support for MediaTek devices ver 0.1
    videobuf2_v4l2      : Driver helper framework for Video for Linux 2
    rtsx_usb_ms     : Realtek USB Memstick Card Host Driver
    memstick        : Sony MemoryStick core driver
    iwlmvm      : The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
    nls_iso8859_1
    videobuf2_common        : Media buffer core framework
    snd_pcm     : Midlevel PCM code for ALSA.
    bluetooth       : Bluetooth Core ver 2.22
    mac80211        : IEEE 802.11 subsystem
    input_leds      : Input -&gt; LEDs Bridge
    snd_seq_midi        : Advanced Linux Sound Architecture sequencer MIDI synth.
    joydev      : Joystick device interfaces
    videodev        : Video4Linux2 core driver
    acer_wmi        : Acer Laptop WMI Extras Driver
    snd_seq_midi_event      : MIDI byte &lt;-&gt; sequencer event coder
    sparse_keymap       : Generic support for sparse keymaps
    libarc4
    ecdh_generic        : ECDH generic algorithm
    mc      : Device node registration for media drivers
    snd_rawmidi     : Midlevel RawMidi code for ALSA.
    ecc
    wmi_bmof        : WMI embedded Binary MOF driver
    snd_seq     : Advanced Linux Sound Architecture sequencer.
    snd_seq_device      : ALSA sequencer device management
    hid_multitouch      : HID multitouch panels
    snd_timer       : ALSA timer interface
    bmc150_accel_i2c        : BMC150 I2C accelerometer driver
    bmc150_accel_core       : BMC150 accelerometer driver
    iwlwifi     : Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
    industrialio_triggered_buffer       : IIO helper functions for setting up triggered buffers
    snd     : Advanced Linux Sound Architecture driver for soundcards.
    kfifo_buf
    cfg80211        : wireless configuration support
    mei_me      : Intel(R) Management Engine Interface
    soundcore       : Core sound module
    mei     : Intel(R) Management Engine Interface
    industrialio        : Industrial I/O core
    processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy     : Processor Thermal Reporting Device Driver
    acer_wireless       : Acer Wireless Radio Control Driver
    processor_thermal_device        : Processor Thermal Reporting Device Driver
    processor_thermal_rfim
    processor_thermal_mbox
    mac_hid
    processor_thermal_rapl
    intel_rapl_common       : Intel Runtime Average Power Limit (RAPL) common code
    soc_button_array
    int3403_thermal     : ACPI INT3403 thermal driver
    int3400_thermal     : INT3400 Thermal driver
    intel_soc_dts_iosf
    int340x_thermal_zone        : Intel INT340x common thermal zone handler
    acpi_thermal_rel        : Intel acpi thermal rel misc dev driver
    sch_fq_codel        : Fair Queue CoDel discipline
    msr     : x86 generic MSR driver
    parport_pc      : PC-style parallel port driver
    ppdev
    lp
    parport
    ramoops     : RAM Oops/Panic logger/driver
    pstore_blk      : pstore backend for block devices
    pstore_zone     : Storage Manager for pstore/blk
    reed_solomon        : Reed Solomon encoder/decoder
    efi_pstore      : EFI variable backend for pstore
    ip_tables       : IPv4 packet filter
    x_tables        : {ip,ip6,arp,eb}_tables backend module
    autofs4
    btrfs
    blake2b_generic     : BLAKE2b generic implementation
    xor
    raid6_pq        : RAID6 Q-syndrome calculations
    libcrc32c       : CRC32c (Castagnoli) calculations
    dm_mirror       : device-mapper mirror target
    dm_region_hash      : device-mapper region hash
    dm_log      : device-mapper dirty region log
    rtsx_usb_sdmmc      : Realtek USB SD/MMC Card Host Driver
    usbhid      : USB HID core driver
    rtsx_usb        : Realtek USB Card Reader Driver
    i915        : Intel Graphics
    drm_buddy       : DRM Buddy Allocator
    i2c_algo_bit        : I2C-Bus bit-banging algorithm
    ttm     : TTM memory manager subsystem (for DRM device)
    drm_display_helper      : DRM display adapter helper
    cec     : Device node registration for cec drivers
    rc_core
    crct10dif_pclmul        : T10 DIF CRC calculation accelerated with PCLMULQDQ.
    crc32_pclmul
    drm_kms_helper      : DRM KMS helper
    ghash_clmulni_intel     : GHASH hash function, accelerated by PCLMULQDQ-NI
    syscopyarea     : Generic copyarea (sys-to-sys)
    sysfillrect     : Generic fill rectangle (sys-to-sys)
    hid_generic     : HID generic driver
    mmc_block       : Multimedia Card (MMC) block device driver
    aesni_intel     : Rijndael (AES) Cipher Algorithm, Intel AES-NI instructions optimized
    sysimgblt       : 1-bit/8-bit to 1-32 bit color expansion (sys-to-sys)
    fb_sys_fops     : Generic file read (fb in system RAM)
    crypto_simd
    i2c_hid_acpi        : HID over I2C ACPI driver
    sdhci_pci       : Secure Digital Host Controller Interface PCI driver
    i2c_i801        : I801 SMBus driver
    cryptd      : Software async crypto daemon
    drm     : DRM shared core routines
    xhci_pci        : xHCI PCI Host Controller Driver
    intel_lpss_pci      : Intel LPSS PCI driver
    ahci        : AHCI SATA low-level driver
    i2c_hid     : HID over I2C core driver
    cqhci       : Command Queue Host Controller Interface driver
    sdhci       : Secure Digital Host Controller Interface core driver
    i2c_smbus       : SMBus protocol extensions support
    xhci_pci_renesas
    intel_lpss      : Intel LPSS core driver
    idma64      : iDMA64 core driver
    libahci     : Common AHCI SATA low-level routines
    hid
    wmi     : ACPI-WMI Mapping Driver
    video       : ACPI Video Driver
    pinctrl_geminilake      : Intel Gemini Lake SoC pinctrl/GPIO driver
    z3fold      : 3-Fold Allocator for Compressed Pages
    lz4     : LZ4 Compression Algorithm
    lz4_compress        : LZ4 compressor
```

**Memory**

````
MemTotal    Total Memory    3819120 KiB 
MemFree Free Memory 304068 KiB  
MemAvailable        328620 KiB  
Buffers     4552 KiB    
Cached      803760 KiB  
SwapCached  Cached Swap 234920 KiB  
Active      704524 KiB  
Inactive        746264 KiB  
Active(anon)        586852 KiB  
Inactive(anon)      659976 KiB  
Active(file)        117672 KiB  
Inactive(file)      86288 KiB   
Unevictable     95504 KiB   
Mlocked     64 KiB  
SwapTotal   Virtual Memory  8716280 KiB 
SwapFree    Free Virtual Memory 5799400 KiB 
Zswap       1113376 KiB 
Zswapped        2419164 KiB 
Dirty       688 KiB 
Writeback       0 KiB   
AnonPages       704248 KiB  
Mapped      149960 KiB  
Shmem       604352 KiB  
KReclaimable        91956 KiB   
Slab        672232 KiB  
SReclaimable        91956 KiB   
SUnreclaim      580276 KiB  
KernelStack     14672 KiB   
PageTables      37496 KiB   
NFS_Unstable        0 KiB   
Bounce      0 KiB   
WritebackTmp        0 KiB   
CommitLimit     10625840 KiB    
Committed_AS        10681752 KiB    
VmallocTotal        -1 KiB  
VmallocUsed     63072 KiB   
VmallocChunk        0 KiB   
Percpu      4192 KiB    
HardwareCorrupted       0 KiB   
AnonHugePages       0 KiB   
ShmemHugePages      0 KiB   
ShmemPmdMapped      0 KiB   
FileHugePages       0 KiB   
FilePmdMapped       0 KiB   
HugePages_Total     0   
HugePages_Free      0   
HugePages_Rsvd      0   
HugePages_Surp      0   
Hugepagesize        2048 KiB    
Hugetlb     0 KiB   
DirectMap4k     818236 KiB  
DirectMap2M     3178496 KiB 
DirectMap1G     2097152 KiB```
````

Comment: I used to experience issues with `chromium` & `firefox` with certain extensions added.. To resolve, I could either remove the extensions (*alas I liked what they gave me*) or learn to mitigate the issue which was my choice... how it appeared to me was *slowing* browser response before freeze... where I'd just remove browser(s) & restart..  thus I'll suggest checking your extensions!   Also consider your apps, as you mention apps that are very inefficient on a Qt5 desktop so you're wasting what RAM you have due to user decisions.  FYI:  If using low RAM (<5GB) I consider apps so they share RAM

Comment: Thanks @guiverc, I really appreciate your prompt answer. What do you mean by "If using low RAM (<5GB) I consider apps so they share RAM"? what is "apps" . What is the most efficient desktop environment for lower RAM?